# Gunicorn on lighttpd - changing base URL for static files from localhost:8080

Tags: django, lighttpd, gunicorn, static-files

Right now I'm working on Django project and this is my first time with running Django app on server (Lighttpd) via gunicorn. The problem is - I run application with gunicorn like this:

```
$PYTHON $MANAGEPATH run_gunicorn -D -b 127.0.0.1:18002 -p $GUNICORN_PIDPATH --log-file $GUNICORN_LOGPATH
```

Part of Django settings.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
from socket import gethostname

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
HOSTNAME = gethostname()

def make_path(path):
    return os.path.join(BASE_DIR, path)

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = make_path('static_root')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In /etc/lighttpd/vhost.d/my_conf.conf I have nice redirect for non-static files:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":82" {
    server.document-root = "/home/mefioo/public_html/generator/static"
    $HTTP["url"] !~ "\.(js|css|gif|jpg|png|ico|txt|swf|html|htm|svg|xlsx)$" {
        proxy.server = ("" => ( "localhost" => (
        "host" => "127.0.0.1",
        "port" => 18002,
        "fix-redirects" => 1
        ) ) )
    }
}
```

Idea - static files like .js or .css are in

```
/home/mefioo/public_html/generator/static
```

(which is proxy to static_root dir in Django app) and should be avaiable from url like

```
my_domain.com:82/my_file.js
```

Rest of the app, with all the urls like this:

```
my_domain.com:82/url
```

should look for django app like that:

```
127.0.0.1:18002/url
```

because of lighttpd conf.

The problem is - when I try to reach my static files, I got 404, because app is looking for

```
localhost:8080/my_file.js
```

instead of

```
my_domain.com:82/my_file.js
```

I don't understand why, especially when I have two instances of that app, one on my own server (second PC, doesn't work) and one on external VPS (works as intended). Am I running gunicorn wrong way, or missing something in lighttpd settings?

Answer (score -1):

I am new to django/gunicorn too but here is how I configured my app:

settings in settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/path to static files"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

I'm not using lighttpd but nginx and here is the configuration:

```
server{
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        access_log off;

location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /path_to_static_files;
    }
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    }
```

After that we have we have to collect the static files in the configured directory. This is done with: `python3 manage.py collectstatic`

All files should be copied in the correct directory and lightppd or nginx can serve them whereas gunicorn do the django/python - part

Comment: I of course did `python manage.py collectstatic`. They were all copied to proper dirs. If i manually paste `my_domain.com:82/my_file.js` the file IS there, the problem is, my app is trying to find it elsewhere...